# Zotac NVida GT640 2GB Video Card Mini HDMI output

Tags: connection, hdmi, tv, external-display, desktop-computer

I cannot get my 42" Samsung TV to show my computer on the HDMI cable which has a mini HDMI cable hooked to the computer.

It works fine if I use the DVI connections from the tv to the computer but I would like to hook it up to HDMI mini to HDMI and can't figure out why it won't work. I have set the settings on the computer to High Definition 1920 x 1080.

I have an updated video driver. Television setting is ok just no transfer, saying `no signal found`.

Answer (score 0):

To connect the display using an HDMI connection (and HDMI cable):

1. Shut down the computer.
2. Turn off the monitor or TV.
3. Connect an HDMI cable to the computer and to the display.
4. Turn on the display, and select the HDMI input as the input source
   to view.
5. Turn on the computer.